# primefaces selectonemenu - setter is not called

Tags: jsf, primefaces, selectonemenu

my selectonemenu does neither call the setter nor the getter after chosing an option.
The map is displayed correctly in the dropdown.

Here is my code:

```
      <p:selectOneMenu id="filter" value="#{myPatientsBean.selectedFilter}"
        valueChangeListener="#{myPatientsBean.activateDefaultFilter}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{myPatientsBean.defaultFilterEntries.entrySet()}" var="map" itemValue="#{map.value}" itemLabel="#{map.key}"/>
        <p:ajax update="patientdata" event="change" />
      </p:selectOneMenu>
```

and here is the backing Bean:

```
    public Map<String, String> getDefaultFilterEntries() {
        return getPatientForFilter().getDefaultFilterEntries(getCurrentUser().hasRight(UserRight.PATIENTVIEWALL));
    }


    public void setSelectedFilter(String index) {
        selectedFilter = Integer.parseInt(index);
        if (selectedFilter == -1) {
            setUseDefaultFilter(false);
        }
    }

    public String getSelectedFilterString() {
        return Integer.toString(selectedFilter);
    }
```

the ValueChangeListener is called too..

Would be very grateful for help.
Tried almost everything :(
A list doesn't solve my Problem neither.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that was not the Problem. I got the solution.
I just got confused with the types of getter and setter... I just had an integer Setter but needed one for a String. The rest of the code is correct.

ty at all

Comment: Ok, so you can close the question.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the valueListener and replace ajax tag as below

```
<p:ajax listener=#{myPatientsBean.activateDefaultFilter}" update="patientdata" />
```

Comment: a valuechangelistener works correct too. That's not the problem.